# Linear transformation on Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis

Show that for $B(X,\mathbb{F})\neq \{0\},B(X,Y)$ is a Banach space if and only if $Y$ is a Banach space.($X,Y$ are normed spaces and $B(X,Y)$ = all continuous linear transformation)

I proved that If $Y$ is Banach space, then $B(X,Y)$ is Banach space.

How to prove if $B(X,Y)$ is Banach space, then $Y$ is Banach space....?

Can I get hints about problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** By the Hahn-Banach Theorem, if $x_0 \neq 0$, there exists a linear and continuous functional $L$ such that $L(x_0) = 1.$ Let $\{y_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $Y$ and consider the linear and continuous maps $$T_n \colon X\to Y,\ T_n(x) := L(x)y_n.$$ The hint is to prove that $\{T_n\}$ is Cauchy in the Banach space $B(X,Y)$. Once you prove this you should be able to conclude the argument.

Comment: If I prove $\{T_n\}$ is the cauchy in $B(X,Y)$, then there exists T $\in$ B(X,Y). . Thus, Tx=L(x)y $\in Y$  implies y $\in Y$. Finally, Y is Banach space. Right?

Comment: You have to be a little bit careful: use that if $T_n \to T$, then $T_n(x_0) \to T(x_0)$. This implies that $y_n = T_n(x_0) \to T(x_0) \in Y$. Hence $Y$ is complete.